# seal gap between door and frame

Tags: outdoor, pest-control, sealing, door-frame

i'm trying to prevent rats from getting into an outdoor shed.  i've thoroughly checked the whole interior, and the only opening is from the front door (see the right door in the picture.  ignore the left door, that only closes fully from the outside).

my intuition is that i should get a foam sealing tape, but i'm concerned that it won't repel pests.  in this situation, i don't really care about thermal or humidity leaking, only something that rats won't chew through.  any suggestions?

[image: gap in door]

Comment: Can the floor be extended out so the door has a "threshold" of sorts to seal against?

Answer (score 1):

Use some sheet metal, rats can and will chew through wood, plastic and foam very easily. Especially if they are already established in the shed. You can bend the sheet metal over and fasten it from both sides.